# Get <hr> in a new line with <p>

Tags: html

I am new to css and my question is this: I want a horizontal line in a new line.

So I thought this would be a good idea:

```
<p><hr/></p>
```

But it instead gives:

```
<p></p>
<hr>
<p></p>
```

Why?

Edit:

**Thank you for the answers.And You re right the question was cryptic. Next time i will use jsfiddle to be more specific ^^**

Comment: That isn't CSS; it's HTML without any styling whatsoever.

Comment: The question is very unclear... what do you mean "horizontal **in** a new line"? What does "it end in this" mean? Can you post an example on jsfiddle.net and describe what's wrong with it?

Comment: Mahan the correct systax is `<br />`

Comment: @Joan.bdm Only in XHTML -- `<br>` and `<hr>` is perfectly fine in HTML

Comment: For anyone who doesn't understand the question: http://jsfiddle.net/6kRp9/

Comment: @Jon Here is a jsfiddle. I want that the hr under the menue. http://jsfiddle.net/nCAk4/  But how i can see in the answers, i know what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTML `<p>` element is a block-level element that can only contain Phrasing Content; that is, text and the markup text contains.

The `<hr>` element represents a thematic break between paragraph elements, and it makes no sense to have one *inside* a paragraph. The standard stipulates that before the `<hr>` block-level element, an implicit `</p>` is generated that closes any open `<p>` elements.

In short, what you're trying to do violates the semantics of paragraphs and horizontal rules.

Answer (score 4):

A paragraph element only allows [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) nested inside it. Since the `</p>` can be omitted, the browser inserts one when it sees "illegal" content such as `<hr>`.

See "permitted content" and "tag omission" at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

Answer (score 3):

The one and only solution is this:

```
<hr style="clear:both;">
```

This code causes an hr across the entire width. It automagically starts at the absolute beginning left of the text area, even when the preceding paragraph has for example a small picture, so it never starts next to that picture.

Comment: This actual ended up being the solution I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The web site return your HTML without change. You can check this in browser network debugger.

As explain by @Wooble, `<p><hr></p>` is incorrect html, but modern browser will try to auto-correct the error :

1. `<p>`, Open a paragraph, ok
2. `<hr>`, Guy you forget to close the paragraph, I add `</p>` before `<hr>`
3. `</p>`, Guy you forget to open the paragraph, I add `<p>` before `</p>`

The result is :

```html
<p>
</p> - added by the broswer
<hr>
<p>  - added by the broswer
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a new line you use `<br />`, `<p></p>` are for paragraphs.