# Paragraph tag attributes not working after using br and hr tag

Tags: html

This code only shows 'this' as center aligned while others are default left aligned.

```html
<p align="center">
  this
  <hr><br> is
  <hr><br> a
  <hr><br> paragraph
  <hr><br> with
  <hr><br> breaks
  <hr><br> and
  <hr><br> horizontal
  <hr><br> rows
  <hr><br>
</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get <hr> in a new line with <p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536157/get-hr-in-a-new-line-with-p)

Comment: Paragraph tags cannot contain horizontal rule tags. An implicit `</p>` is added before the first `<hr>`. You can see this in action using your browser's [DOM inspector](https://i.imgur.com/13GoqKj.png). Also don't use the obsolete `align` attribute in place of CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML `<hr>` element represents a thematic break between paragraph-level elements.
So using `<hr>` element inside a paragraph closes the opened `<p>` element automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything inside a div and use align in that div this will make all items centered

```html
<div  style="text-align: center;">
  <p>
  this <hr><br> 
  is <hr><br>
  a <hr><br>
  paragraph <hr><br>
  with <hr><br>
  breaks <br><hr>
  and <br><hr>
  horizontal <br><hr>
  rows<br><hr>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that worked but why the p align does not worked??

Comment: Please don't recommend or use the `align` attribute on `<div>` or `<p>` tags. It is obsolete and shouldn't be used. Text should be centered using CSS properties.

Comment: thanks cfillion I am new to html and css so I don't know a much about it thanks for help :))